# Android studio navigation drawer not fitting correctly

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I've thoroughly searched but couldn't find my answer, sorry if this a stupid post.

My navigation drawer won't set when I declare android:layout_gravity="start" I've been trying to solve this issue however I cannot find it anywhere online. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. Here is a screenshot of what it navigation drawer looks like on a S7 device.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL8re.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_homepage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="mypackagename.homepage">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<include layout="@layout/navigation_action">

</include>

<Button
    android:text="Add a post"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
    android:id="@+id/addNewPost"
    android:onClick="addNewPost"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<include layout="@layout/main_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

</include>
```

Comment: Can you add an image of what you expect it to look like? (drawer not fitting correctly does not explain what you want it to do).

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, this is where i want the drawer to start as shown in the image with the black box and arrow instead of the main page.

Comment: http://i68.tinypic.com/11u9evn.png

Comment: @Noskes you mean that you want to leave space at the begiging of drawer items?

Comment: does your drawer remain open on app start up? and do you want it not to?